# Get the keys of an already typed object as types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
const obj1 = {
    foo: 'bar',
    goo: 'car',
    hoo: 'dar',
    ioo: 'far'
} as const

const obj2 = {
    koo: 'gar',
    loo: 'har',
    moo: 'jar',
    noo: 'kar'
} as const

type KeysOfObj1 = keyof typeof obj1  // "foo" | "goo" | "hoo" | "ioo"
type ValuesOfObj1 = typeof obj1[KeysOfObj1]  // "bar" | "car" | "dar" | "far"
type KeysOfObj2 = keyof typeof obj2  // "koo" | "loo" | "moo" | "noo"
type ValuesOfObj2 = typeof obj2[KeysOfObj2]  // "gar" | "har" | "jar" | "kar"

type OtherObj = Record<string, ValuesOfObj1 | ValuesOfObj2>

const obj3: OtherObj = {
    hello: obj1.foo,
    world: obj2.koo
} as const

const obj4: OtherObj = {
    hi: obj1.hoo,
    anotherWorld: obj2.moo
} as const

type KeysOfObj3 = keyof typeof obj3  // string
type KeysOfObj4 = keyof typeof obj4  // string
```

so I think the code explains itself. My question is
on the last two lines, how can I get keys of obj3 and obj4 as type
now I am getting string as those types but I want to get these:

```
type KeysOfObj3 = keyof typeof obj3  // "hellow", "world"
type KeysOfObj4 = keyof typeof obj4  // "hi", "anotherWorld"
```

Please read through the comments as well. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the line `type OtherObj = Record<string, ValuesOfObj1 | ValuesOfObj2>`, you are explicitly typing the key to type of `string`.

So when you do `keyof typeof obj3`, it looks at `Record<string, ...>` and uses that.

If you want to add typechecking, you'll either have to use a type alias with generics or a function with generics

```js
type OtherObj<T extends string> = Record<T, ValuesOfObj1 | ValuesOfObj2>

// Define keys explicitly
const obj3: OtherObj<'hello' | 'world'> = {
    hello: obj1.foo,
    world: obj2.koo
} as const
```

Otherwise, if you don't like the redundant verbosity, you can sacrifice negligible (depending on who you ask) runtime code. This using the inferencing from type parameters to infer the return value.

```js
const createObj = <K extends string>(
  obj: Record<K, ValuesOfObj1 | ValuesOfObj2>
) => obj

const obj4 = createObj({
    hi: obj1.hoo,
    anotherWorld: obj2.moo,
    foo: 'foobar' //Error thrown! <-- this is invalid value
} as const)
```

[See this on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAyyvm)

Comment: Thanks, the second one worked for me(createObj). Could you explain what does that mean though?

Comment: We use a function since we can derive the ReturnType based on the parameters and TypeScript's generic system. This kind of generic inferencing is only possible on functions/classes, hence why the first option we have to explicitly type the keys. Read more about generics here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html or about the inference system in TS: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html

Comment: In createObj, can I use generic for the second arg.                                                   const createObj = <K extends string, U>(
  obj: Record<K, U | ValuesOfObj2>
) => obj

Comment: You can, but you may run into some trouble inferring the keys again. This is because TS does not support partial inferencing with generics. You can basically either know the keys ahead of time, know the values ahead of time, know none of them, know both of them. But you cannot know one or the other and infer the other values. This is a known limitation. See it here in action: https://tsplay.dev/w1yyAw, or read the PR regarding this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I dont suppose  this would be possible in TS.    const createObj = <K extends string, U>( obj: Record<K, U | ValuesOfObj2> ) => obj  and then const createObj1 = <string, ValuesOfObj1>CreateObj and createObj3 = <string, ValueObj3>createObj

Comment: This indeed works as a workaround to partial generics, see here: https://tsplay.dev/mAyKvm